# Ubuntu 12.04 Apache Sluggish Performance

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system

I've got two installs of ubuntu 12.04 running on VMware ESX host servers and I'm getting very sluggish performance loading web pages from apache compared to the other servers I have on the same data farm running the same web pages on ubuntu 10.04

The only difference I've noticed with the build on 12.04 is that the DNS is working differently so I've added named servers to the main interfaces setup?

Could this be a issue with the networking so the DNS or host files are wrong?

I know this is going to sound a general question but any ideas on why ubuntu 12.04 performance is sluggish to load web content compared to the same build, network, disk access as the other VM's running on ubuntu 10.04?

I can add more information if required but I can't see anything wrong from the build?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: Do you have `HostnameLookups` switched on somewhere in your apache configuration?

Comment: yep thats off - it has the same set up as the other server - I'm lost at the moment